# Print string after equals to sign in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string

I have lots of lines in a text file. One line for example:

```
838: DEBUG, GD, Parameter(Player_Appearance_Model) = GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)
```

Can somebody please tell me how to print all the string after the equals to sign ("="). For instance, in the above case, output should be "GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)".

I tried to split the line and print the last index, however, it gives me "0.09)" answer, which is, of course, incorrect.

Comment: Did you split by the equal sign or comma? Splitting by the equal sign should give you the correct result.

Comment: What if the string contains multiple `=`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary, fortunately it does not contain any multiple =

Comment: if you found your answer, please do mark as such

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need a regex, just `split()` it:

```
>>> s = "838: DEBUG, GD, Parameter(Player_Appearance_Model) = GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)"
>>> s.split(" = ")[1]
'GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)'
```

or:

```
>>> s.split("=")[1].strip()
'GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`str.partition()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> s = "838: DEBUG, GD, Parameter(Player_Appearance_Model) = GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)"
>>> print s.partition('= ')[2]
GaussianDistribution(0.28, 0.09)
```

This is useful incase the data you need has another equals sign in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
def GetPart(s,part=1):
    out = s.split('=')[part].strip()      #only '=', spaces will be removed
    return out

>>> s = 'abcd=efgh'
>>> GetPart(s)
>>> 'efgh'
>>> s = 'abcd=  efgh'                     #note extra spaces
>>> GetPart(s)
>>> 'efgh'
>>> s = 'abcd   =  efgh  '                #even more space before/after
>>> GetPart(s)
>>> 'efgh'
```

and of course:

```
>>> s = 'abcd=efgh'                       
>>> GetPart(s,0)                          #first part
>>> 'abcd'
```